# Why a nil error returned from strings.Builder WriteString in golang, is it necessary?

Tags: go

When reviewed my colleague's code, I found that a returned `err` has been ignored, though we would not do that in general:

```golang
b := new(strings.Builder)
b.WriteString("Hello, World!") // ignore err
```

The source code for `WriteString` declares it may return an error, but in fact it never will (always returning `nil` for the error value):

```golang
// WriteString appends the contents of s to b's buffer.
// It returns the length of s and a nil error.
func (b *Builder) WriteString(s string) (int, error) {
    b.copyCheck()
    b.buf = append(b.buf, s...)
    return len(s), nil
}
```

What would the issues be, if any, with removing the error return, as follows?

```golang
func (b *Builder) WriteString(s string) int {
    b.copyCheck()
    b.buf = append(b.buf, s...)
    return len(s)
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the biggest reason is that it's useful to satisfy interfaces like `io.StringWriter` -- without the error, that wouldn't be possible.  Other things that satisfy that interface do need to potentially return an error, and it's useful to have the interface for interoperability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [changelist](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/74931/) which introduces `strings.Builder` includes a lot of comments about trying to make this API similar to `bytes.Buffer`.

For instance,

> That's how a bytes.Buffer behaves, after all, and we're supposed to be a subset of a bytes.Buffer.

Looking at the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Buffer.WriteRune) for some `bytes.Buffer` functions, it mentions

> WriteRune appends the UTF-8 encoding of Unicode code point r to the buffer, returning its length and an error, which is always nil but is included to match bufio.Writer's WriteRune.

It looks like they're basically trying to design an API that's similar to other interfaces in Golang's standard library. Even though the always-`nil` error is redundant, it allows the `Builder` to match existing interfaces that would accept `bytes.Buffer` or `bufio.Writer`. One such interface is [`io.StringWriter`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#StringWriter), which looks like

```golang
type StringWriter interface {
    WriteString(s string) (n int, err error)
}
```

The `err` return value here is useful since other `StringWriter` implementations could possibly return errors.

Comment: thanks for your answer which solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Go, it's quite common to return a value and error. So you can check the error is not null, if no error then easily use the returned value.
In other words, if it receives an error from a function then it indicates there was a problem with the function called.

Comment: I think their question was about the fact that in this case, the documentation clearly states that this function _always_ returns a `nil` error, and the three-line body of the function shows that this is true.  So they seem to be asking... "Wait, why bother if it's always `nil`?"